# Is there any elegant function to find an array in array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to check if an array contains an array of values rather then a value, for example

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.contains([1, 2]); // returns true
// and
arr.contains([1, 5]); // must be false
```

There is a method called contains in `underscore` `_.contains` but it works like `.indexof()` in javascript instead it returns true and false and only find a value and not an array

Also there is a method [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in javascript that also take single input rather of an array

Comment: _"I want to check if an array contains an array of values rather then a value"_ Is requirement to check if array contains any value that is an array ; or if array contains values which are all arrays ?

Comment: @guest271314 sir actually I want to check if second array has all the keys present in first array I want to check with `AND`

Comment: for example `[1,2,3,4].contains([1,4])` must return `true` where as `[1,2,3,4].contains([1,9])` must return false, hope this makes sense, I'm for now using underscores intersection and second array with intersection result it must be same, its still long procedure....

Answer (score 1):

> actually I want to check if second array has all the keys present in
>   first array I want to check with `AND`
>
> for example `[1,2,3,4].contains([1,4])` must return true where as `[1,2,3,4].contains([1,9])` must return false, hope this makes sense,
>   I'm for now using underscores intersection and second array with
>   intersection result it must be same, its still long procedure....

You could use `Array.prototype.includes()` within a `for` loop

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

function contains(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, included = true; i < arr.length
       ; included = included && this.includes(arr[i]), i++);
  return included
}

Array.prototype.contains = contains;

console.log(arr.contains([1, 4]), arr.contains([9, 1]), arr.contains([1, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of every and indexOf

```
[1, 2].every(function(e) { return [1, 2, 3].indexOf(e) !== -1 });
```

would evaluate to true and

```
[1, 5].every(function(e) { return [1, 2, 3].indexOf(e) !== -1 });
```

would evaluate to false

The syntax would be a lot shorter in ES6 with arrow functions

```
[1, 2].every(e => [1, 2, 3].indexOf(e) !== -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function contains(arr, arr2) {
  return arr2.every(function (el) {
    return arr.indexOf(el) > -1;
  });
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
contains(arr, [1, 2]); // true
contains(arr, [1, 5]); // false
```

Alternatively, you could add a method to the prototype if you wanted the `[].includes`-style syntax, but call it something else - I've used `hasAll`.

```
if (!('hasAll' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.hasAll = function(arr) {
    return arr.every(function(el) {
      return this.indexOf(el) > -1;
    }, this);
  }

arr.hasAll([1, 2])); // true
arr.hasAll([1, 5])); // false
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tbqjd4se/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var searchArr = [1,2];
var isSearchArrAvailable = searchArr.filter( function(value){ if ( arr.indexOf( value ) == -1 ) { return true } else { return false; } } ).length == 0;
console.log( "is SearchArr Available " + isSearchArrAvailable );//this will print true
```

while `var searchArr = [1,5]` will print `false`.

You can refactor it into a function

```
function hasEveryElement(arr, searchArr)
{
   return searchArr.filter( function(value){ if ( arr.indexOf( value ) == -1 ) { return true } else { return false; } } ).length == 0;
}
console.log( hasEveryElement([1,2,3], [1,2]) ) ;
console.log( hasEveryElement([1,2,3], [1,4]) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
var arr = [1,2,3];
var temparr=[1,2];
var st=ArrOfArrSt(arr,temparr); 

function ArrOfArrSt(arr,temparr){
    var stArr= new Array(); 
    if(temparr.length>0)
        for(j in temparr){
                if(arr.indexOf(temparr[j])==-1){
                   stArr.push('0'); 
                }
        }
  return (stArr.length>0)?0:1; //whole array 0=not belong to / 1=belong to  
}
```